# path completion in major IDEs

Tags: eclipse, autocomplete, xcode, ide, intellij-idea

In vim I can use the ctrl-x ctrl-f shortcut for autocompleting file paths, a nice feature that I have missed all the time in all major IDEs, I am wondering how I can do it in the following:

- eclipse
- intellij idea
- xcode